# drawing an animated line that erases itself

Tags: iphone, ipad, drawing, line, draw

Can someone advise what method is used to for the following scenario:

user touches the screen then drags their finger away from this point and a line is drawn, but as they move their finger up and down the line follows their finger as a straight line.

example is like the centre of a clock where the minute hand is fixed at the centre and the user drags the other end around the clock.  The minute hand glides around as a permanent straight line not erasing the detail beneath it....

hope I explained that right?

thanks for some pointers

Comment: You'll have to learn about Quartz to draw the straight line.

Simply use touchesBegan to set the start point in a variable CGPoint.

In touchesMoved, set the end point in another CGPoint variable, and then use setNeedsDisplay to redraw the line.

You'll have to learn about how to use drawRect, and setNeedsDisplay.

Answer (score 2):

Use This code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);  
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineJoinMiter);

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), endPoint.x,endPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

   [self setNeedsDisplay];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

just save the x/y coordinate of the point where the drag started, and the point where the finger is after a few milliseconds, then calculate the direction vector

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_vector

with the calculated formula, always just fetch the fingers x or y position, and use it to calculate the counterpart

Comment: @joe, yeah i see i misunderstood the question. didn't read the erase and redraw to new finger position part

Comment: Hi, thanks for answers, I already use touches began and touches moved and get a line drawn as I move my finger.  However let me explain...touchesbegan at 10,10 and as I move to 10,200 the line is drawn.  Now without lifting my finger I move my finger to 100,100.  The line get drawn with an angle leading off the the right.  What I need is as I move to 100,100 the line starting at 10,10 extends down as a straight line to my finger,  like a hand of a clock leaving the content underneath unchanged

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks!  Basically I am trying understand how to replicate the feature of the line drawing and moving of the line that has a fixed anchor at the initial touch and that grows in length as the finger moves from the anchor but also allow for the rotation.  A great example is the free iPhone app wordsearch unlimited that shows exactly what I'm trying to do.... ;-)